# JQuery slimScroll with border-radius in table not working in IE 8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, slimscroll

I am using JQuery slimScroll plugin to make a custom scroll bar in a div. Inside that div I have a table, I want to make first  and last  of the table row rounded and it is working fine with other browsers except IE 8. In IE 8 when I scroll, the first and last  moves little slower.

I have attached the picture too. [image]

Here is the table:

```
<table>
    <c:forEach var="lists" items="${viewGroupListByUser}" varStatus="status">
    <tr style="position: relative;">
        <td ><img alt="" src="../images/group/group.jpg" style="margin-left: 10px;"></td>
        <td id="gn_${lists.groupID}" width="245px" style="padding-left: 10px !important;">${lists.groupName}</td>
        <td id="gd_${lists.groupID}"  width="190px">${lists.groupDetail}</td>
        <td width="120px"><a href="viewGroupPage?groupID=${lists.groupID}&groupName=${lists.groupName}" class="link_button">View</a></td>
        <td width="120px"><a href="#" onclick="showEditGroup(this)" id="${lists.groupID}" class="link_button">Edit</a></td>
        <td width="120px" class='last-child' style="position: relative;"><a href="deleteGroup/${lists.groupID}" class="link_button">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

This is the css:

```
.group_manage_list_main{
    margin-left: 89px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 860px;
    height: 450px;
    position: relative;
}
.group_manage_list_main table{
    border-collapse: separate;
    width: 830px;
    border-spacing: 0 15px;
    margin-top: -14px;
    position: relative;
}
.last-child { 
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
    border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    behavior: url("../css/PIEFiles/PIE.htc");
}
```

Please someone help me, I am stuck here since 2 days. thanx

Answer (score 1):

That's because is a css3 property which doesn't have support in IE8 the

[Here's the w3schools reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp)

[Mozilla Developer reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

**"UPDATE"**

You're using a Css3 selector and also doesn't have support in IE8 using jquery you could used a selector like

```
$(".group_manage_list_main td:last") //not tested
```

[Last child w3 school doc](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp)

Comment: I have made rounded border using PIE, which works in IE8. My problem is while scrolling the div, the last child and first child is only shifting down or slower than other <td>

Comment: The round border could be, but the css selector doesn't have support

Comment: I just tried to apply for whole <td> border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0; and now whole table row is slower than data inside it... what is the problem here... i am dying